# How to add home/ settings buttons to PhoneGap (webview)

Tags: jquery-ui, css, cordova

I going to develop an app using PhoneGap, which will contain **home** and **settings** buttons in form of icons on the top of every webview like an actionbar menu in android. I'm using generated template from ThemeRoller (CSS) for JQuery Mobile. Can anyone to advise with some examples?

Example here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72519118/ThemeRoller.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage" data-theme="a">

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secondpage" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#homepage">Home</a>
        <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
        <a href="#settings" data-icon="gear">Settings</a>       
    </div>   
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="settings" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#homepage">Home</a>
</div>
</div>
```

If you want to create a home button with Jquery Mobile simply do something like this :)

Put the link with the text "home" where you want, and you can ofc just style it as you want :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works amazing ;)

Answer (score 0):

-Put image tag in-place of anchor tag in Header

```
<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />

 <a href="#homepage">Home</a>
```